# Responsive design error in Drupal

Tags: mobile, drupal, responsive-design, drupal-7

I have a responsible theme in Drupal and when visiting my site on a mobile device I get a uncomplete view that is deformed. (In the beginning the mobile version worked)

When visiting the site on a mobile device, the site recognises the advice and makes the switch to the mobile site, BUT then I see that the mobile website is displayed like the this: red = mobile site, white = void
[How it is at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bekPL.jpg)

The idea is that the entire screen is red. :)

I used a different theme = same problem.

I uploaded a new version of Drupal = same problem.

Can you please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the default theme built into drupal 7. Make the theme "Seven" as the default and see if that resolves your issue. If that still doesn't solve your issue, try clearing your cache in drupal via admin > config > performance

If that still persists, try turning off cache on that page completely.

If all else fails install Drupal 7 with NO modules enabled and see what you get. Then turn on each module on one at a time and see how that goes.